# trying to call a class but it gives me errors: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, class, oop

I created a class called `PlacePiece` which will be called in the `Game` class. but when I call it in `Game` Class it gives me the error:

> actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

how do I fix it and what's causing it? I do not know how to fix it and been trying to solve it for eternity. I'm also new to coding so any feedback can help

```
public class Game {
    private Board gBoard;
    private PlacePiece placePiece; 

    public Game() {
        gBoard = new Board();
        PlacePiece.placePiece();
   }
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlacePiece {

    public void placePiece(char[][] gBoard) {

        System.out.print("Game has begun, please enter where you would like to place (1~9):");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int placement = scan.nextInt();
  
        System.out.println(placement);       

        char piece = ' ';              
        switch(placement){
            case 1: gBoard[0][0] = piece;
                break;
            case 2: gBoard[0][2] = piece;
                break;
            case 3: gBoard[0][4] = piece;
                break;
            case 4: gBoard[2][0] = piece;
                break;
            case 5: gBoard[2][2] = piece;
                break;
            case 6: gBoard[2][4] = piece;
                break;
            case 7: gBoard[3][0] = piece;
                break;
            case 8: gBoard[3][2] = piece;
                break;
            case 9: gBoard[3][4] = piece;
                break;
        }  
        for(char[] row : gBoard){
            for(char c : row){
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually initialized any `PlacePiece` variable and your method isn't static, so how do you want to call it? Also in your `placePiece` function you should pass `char[][] gBoard`, that you aren't passing.

My guess is that you are trying to make a game and don't know how, sou you just copied some function from internet without knowing the function.

So, in your `Board` class I bet that you have something like this:

```
public class Board {
    private char[][] board; // you should initialize it in constructor

    public char[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }
}
```

Then you should create your `placePiece` variable in `Game` class and use it:

```
public class Game {
    private Board gBoard;
    private PlacePiece placePiece; 

    public Game() {
        gBoard = new Board();
        placePiece = new PlacePiece();
        placePiece.placePiece(gBoard.getBoard()); // you have to pass variable to placePiece() function
    }
}
```

I don't think you know, what you're doing otherwise you wouldn't have made these mistakes, so I highly recommend you taking some Java tutorial, so you have some foundation and then start doing more complex tasks.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. you are right that I'm kind of all over the place but I'm just trynna learn to program in my high school class. but I didn't copy any codes :(